# Injection of EntityManager in Servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I want to inject an EM into a Servlet, the persistence unit is declared in the EJB JAR. I have an EAR with an EJB JAR and a WAR. 
The problem is that I get this error:

> Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the
>   persistence-context-ref-name [cvu.JpaServlet/em] in the scope of the
>   module called

If I put the persistence.xml in the WAR it works ok, but I don't want to do that.

Can I get an EntityManager from the PersistenceUnit (persistence.xml) declared in EJB JAR ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the ejb jar to your wars classpath.

In general you should inject an EntityManagerFacotry into a Servlet, not an EntityManager, as a Servlet is shared.

You could also wrap your persistence using SessionBeans.

Comment: yeah I know, but I just want to test it :) I will try the thing with ejb jar in war's classpath .. The Servlet does see the SessionBeans, why can't he see the Persistence Unit !?

Answer (score 0):

I moved all my persistence classes & persistence.xml into a `persist.jar`, and put it in `ear/lib`. Now it works from EJB and from WAR. If you put the `persistence.xml` just in your `name.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` you won't be able to use it in EJB. If you put it in EJB you won't be able to use `@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory` in WAR. For you to access it in WAR you can put it also in `WEB-INF/lib/persist.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml`. But better is in EAR.